# How to create smooth animated hover background following pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a product list on much box, i want something different from others, and i found that. Here's something product list i want to create :

http://dunked.com/showcase

As you see on second product list, their can move the hover background smoothly, and the different is that hovered background follow the pointer in 4 directions (up, right, down, left).

I see another sample like this, but its only 2 direction (right to left and left to right)

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/zv2gb78L/][2]
```

Can someone help me what the algorithm their use to create that? or you can show me something like that. Thanks in advance

Comment: ow yes this the correct sorry https://jsfiddle.net/zv2gb78L/

Comment: where is images? your need hover effect on images right?

Comment: what i want is when i hovered to red box, the arrow img (back of red box) follow my pointer to left , right (its works) and up, down (i dont know how to make that, therefore I ask here)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Change snippet as expected result

```js
$(function() {
   
    $(' #da-thumbs > li ').each( function() { $(this).hoverdir(); } );

   });
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* General Demo Style */
body{
 font-family: Cambria, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", Georgia, serif;
 background: #fff url(../images/bg.png) repeat top left;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #333;
}
a{
 color: #555;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.container{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 min-height: 750px;
}
.clr{
 clear: both;
 padding: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.container > header{
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align: center;
}
.container > header > span{
 font-family: 'Alegreya SC', Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #719dab;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.container > header h1{
 font-size: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #498ea5;
 padding: 5px 0px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.container > header h1 span{
 font-weight: 700;
}
.container > header h2{
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
 color: #6190ca;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.container > header p{
 font-style: italic;
 color: #aaa;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
/* Header Style */
.codrops-top{
 line-height: 24px;
 font-size: 11px;
 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 z-index: 9999;
 position: relative;
 font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
 box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.codrops-top a{
 padding: 0px 10px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: #333;
 display: inline-block;
}
.codrops-top a:hover{
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.codrops-top span.right{
 float: right;
}
.codrops-top span.right a{
 float: left;
 display: block;
}
/* Demo Buttons Style */
.codrops-demos{
    text-align:center;
 display: block;
 line-height: 30px;
 padding: 5px 0px;
}
.codrops-demos a{
    display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px 4px;
 padding: 0px 6px;
 color: #aaa;
 line-height: 20px; 
 font-size: 13px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.codrops-demos a:hover{
 color: #333;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.codrops-demos a:active{
 background: #fff;
}
.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover{
 background: #f6f6f6;
}

.da-thumbs {
 list-style: none;
 width: 984px;
 height: 600px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px auto;
 padding: 0;
}
.da-thumbs li {
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 8px;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.da-thumbs li a,
.da-thumbs li a img {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
}
.da-thumbs li a {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.da-thumbs li a div {
 position: absolute;
 background: #333;
 background: rgba(75,75,75,0.7);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.da-thumbs li a div span {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin: 40px 20px 20px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 -10px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/DirectionAwareHoverEffect/js/modernizr.custom.97074.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.hoverdir/1.1.1/jquery.hoverdir.min.js"></script>

<section>
    <ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/1.jpg" />
       <div><span>Menu by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/2.jpg" />
       <div><span>TN Aquarium  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/3.jpg" />
       <div><span>Mr. Crabs  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/4.jpg" />
       <div><span>Gallery  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li> 
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/5.jpg" />
       <div><span>Ice Cream  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/6.jpg" />
       <div><span>My Muse  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/7.jpg" />
       <div><span>Natalie  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/8.jpg" />
       <div><span>App Preview  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/9.jpg" />
       <div><span>Cornwall Map  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/10.jpg" />
       <div><span>final AD logo  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/11.jpg" />
       <div><span>Land  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       <img src="images/12.jpg" />
       <div><span>Seahorse  by Fadhly Permata</span></div>
      </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </section>
```

Comment: Tapi yang saya maksud bukan seperti itu, look the sample link above gan.

Comment: yap, i know what your expected result... but they've used lot of Javascripts code.. look at their **lib.min.js** file inside the page, they've put the animation script on this file.

Comment: I want know the algorithm their use

Comment: then, my javascript above is enough.. my script have ability to read mouseenter position (from left or right position).

Comment: for easy use, you can use jquery hoverdir plugin, as they've used in their website. you can take it from [link](https://github.com/webmandesign/jquery.hoverdir)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115378/discussion-between-engkus-kusnadi-and-fadhly-permata).

Comment: @EngkusKusnadi Check my edited snippet bro.. Sorry i can do any chat while on office ;)  jangan lupa mark as answer-nya ya... kan udah pas banget tuh hasilnya wkwkwkwk